# How to generate a .cod file for blackberry 6/7 using IBM Worklight and eclipse?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-webworks, ibm-mobilefirst

I have built a Worklight Hybrid application using IBM Worklight. Now I am trying to generate a .cod file to run the application in a BlackBerry device.

Does IBM worklight provide any facility to generate a .cod file for BlackBerry?
Can anyone guide me on how to generate a .cod file?

Comment: is your question resolved? please mark as answered.

Answer (score 2):

IBM Worklight does not provide tools to generate the .cod file for BlackBerry OS 6/7 (or 10). To accomplish this, you need to use the [BlackBerry-provided "Ripple" emulator](http://developer.blackberry.com/html5/downloads/), through which you can also generate a .cod file.

The following [IBM Worklight Getting Started](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html) training modules explain how to work with BlackBerry in Worklight:

- [Setting up your BlackBerry 6 and 7 development environment](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v506/01_04_Setting_up_your_BlackBerry_6_and_7_development_environment.pdf)
- [Previewing your application on BlackBerry 6 and 7](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v506/02_04_Previewing_your_application_on_BlackBerry_6_and_7.pdf)
- [General information when developing for BlackBerry 6 and 7](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v506/03_08_General_information_when_developing_for_BlackBerry_6_and_7.pdf)

And these are the steps to follow, in general:

1. Install the [BlackBerry WebWorks SDK](http://developer.blackberry.com/html5/downloads/) for BlackBerry 6/7
2. Get the code signing keys by [following the BlackBerry guides](https://www.blackberry.com/SignedKeys/codesigning.html)
3. Install the [Ripple Chrome extension](http://developer.blackberry.com/html5/downloads/)
4. Generate your BlackBerry project using Worklight
5. Setup Ripple with your BlackBerry project (explained in the training modules)
6. Generate .cod file

You can now install the .cod by either using the BlackBerry device manager software or via CMD using JavaLoader or via Ripple. [Read these instructions from BlackBerry](https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/loading_your_app_on_a_smartphone_1876977_11.html).